# Yii Documentation: Generate Html Help Project files

Tags: yii, documentation-generation, html-help

I need to generate **MS html help project files** (that is html/js/image files plus .hhp, .hhk, and .hhc)  from Yii Docs build system but I'm yet to find how to do It. I don't need a compiled CHM, just the project files. I work from Ubuntu Linux

Any pointer or direct help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed PHP Unit and Selenium extension via pear
Then I went on to run phing in yii/build dir with commands

```
cd yiidir/build
phing doc
```

check API sub directory and it have all necessary files to make CHM.
Since I needed uncompiled files then I just ended here but you can go ahead and compile to CHM